# Root level `beforeEachFile` and `afterEachFile`

Tags: mocha.js

I am trying to do a root-level `before` that runs before each test file, and after each test file completes. So in other words I want it to run before and after the "top most" describe.

The only way I got this to work was by adding into each of my files top-most `describe` a `before` and `after`. However it is getting very redundant, can I just do it at root level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does wrapping all of your describes in another describe solve *it* (no pun intended)?

```
describe('all stuff', () => {

  before(() => {

  }

  describe('something', () => {
    it('...', ()=> {

    })

    it('...', ()=> {

    })

  })

  after(() => {

  })

})
```